# How can I make an existing time series more volatile?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, linear-regression

I have an existing time series that I would like to make more volatile, or more variance.
I would like the highs to be higher and the lows to be lower.
The time series is somewhat stationary and I would like the amplification of the numbers in the series to keep the same slope. In other words, I would like the mean of the series to remain the same and the standard deviation of the series to increase.

Below is my attempt.
I fit a line to it with linear regression. This part works okay. The problem comes when I try to make every number above the regression line higher and every number below it low at a scale. See the picture below for how this code works. It's not giving me a spikey, volatile series I want. It's just dividing the highs and lows further apart.
Sorry, I don't know math notation, and I'm trying to do this in Python, so I'd really appreciate it if you could make your answer legible to a math illiterate like me.

```
def slope(series):
    x = [x for x in range(int(len(series)))]
    fit = np.polyfit(x, series, 1)
    fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)
    return fit_fn(x)

ss = slope(time_series)

tu = []
w = 0
for n, z in enumerate(time_series):
    b = z * 1.3
    if ss[n] < z:
        r = (z - b)
    else:
        r = (z + b) 
    w += r
    tu.append(r)
```

This was my attempt.

[image]

This is the original.

[image]

What I want is just a time series with more extreme swings. I want everything to scale from the mean trend line.

Comment: How about only tu.append$((z-ss[n])*1.3 + ss[n])$ inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are looking for is a [mean preserving spread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-preserving_spread).

First of all, your linear regression doesn't really make sense here: it is just demeaning your data. You can just multiply the deviations from the mean by some constant `konstant` and add the mean. You can elegantly do that with list comprehensions in Python as follows:

```
time_series = norm.rvs(size=100)
mean = np.mean(time_series)
konstant = 10
time_series_2 = [(x-mean)*konstant + mean for x in time_series ]
```

Plotting the series together:

```
plt.title("Comparing Series")
plt.plot(time_series, label = 'Original')
plt.plot(time_series_2, label = 'Mean-Preserving Spread')
plt.legend()
```

The result is:

[image]